# DataTables warning: table id=extension - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

Tags: ajax, codeigniter-3

> DataTables warning: table id=user - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For
>   more information about this error, please see
>   http://datatables.net/tn/3

```
  <table id="user" class="table datatable-responsive-row-control">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Username</th>
                            <th>Account</th>
                            <th>data CID</th>
                            <th>Type</th>
                        <?php if(!$this->session->userdata('type') == '0') { ?>
                            <th>Action</th>
                         <?php } ?>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#user').DataTable({

```
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax":{
            "url": "<?php echo base_url('user/use_data') ?>",
            "dataType": "json",
            "type": "POST",
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "accountid" },
            { "data": "dataid" },
            { "data": "type" },
        <?php if(!$this->session->userdata('type') == '0') { ?>
            { "data": "actions" },
        <?php } ?>
        ]
    });    
});
```

Comment: Please improve your question by reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's unclear what you've done and what you try to do.

Comment: Did you actually go to the link the error message provides? It's pretty clear about what the problem is and how to fix it.